# Iterating a function to display updated position every run in VPython

Tags: python, vpython

The position of a box is updated by sending the position data in a list currentTargetPos. 
But when I run the following code in some loop, VPython displays a trail of all the positions box was given. There is this situation with the display. I want to display the most recent placement of box. How do I update the scene ?

```
from visual import *
bluebox=box(pos=vector(currentTargetPos[0], currentTargetPos[1], currentTargetPos[2]), size=  (1,1,1),color=color.cyan)
while 1:
    rate(100)
    break
```

Edit: I do not have velocity data for the box. So I can not update the position using velocity. So this is basically not an animation in strict sense since while loop always breaks. But, I want to make it look like animation.

Comment: Have issues with the answer? Please accept, if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the above code every time you update the position, then you're creating a new box each time, which would show multiple copies of it, at each used position.

Your loop, as shown doesn't really do anything. If you want to step through a list of values, you could do that inside the loop (I'm assuming that `currentTargetPos` is a list of components, x,y,z,,x,y,z,x,y,z,etc.):

```
counter = 0
while 1:
    rate(100)
    bluebox.pos = vector(currentTargetPos[z]+currentTargetPos[z+1]+currentTargetPos[z+2])
    counter = counter + 3
```